# ksoap2 HttpTransport class not found

Tags: android, ksoap2

I am using KSOAP2 in an Android application.

I found examples that uses the HttpTransport class but eclipse can't find it in the ksoap2-android-assembly-2.6.5-jar-with-dependencies.jar.

However the HttpTransportSE class is found.

Why can't I use the HttpTransport class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First check if the jar file is properly included in your class path.

Assuming your class path is set properly and the jar file is added correctly. Then change the jar files extension from .jar to .zip, unzip the jar file and then check whether the HttpTransport class is within the zip file.

If the class file "HttpTransport.class" is not there in the jar file then it will not be able to find in your code.

Comment: The class is not in the jar file. Thanks user_CC.